# How to stop mysql query execution if it takes a long time

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu-18.04

I need recommendations from an experts of Mysql (innodb on v 5.6+)

- Server: Ubuntu 18.04
- Mysql - 5.6
- nginx (latest)
- RAM 1gb, proc 2x2.4

What is the problem?

Depending from the some queries execution time takes too long.

Is there any way to stop the execution of the query and return (for example false) if it takes more than N seconds?

Thanks

Mysql indexes is ok, querying and grouping is ok.

Comment: Maybe mess with `SET SESSION MAX_EXECUTION_TIME`

Comment: 1GB of memory is really tight these days. It's probably not a huge issue, but that leaves very little for InnoDB cache, so getting more may help.

Comment: TY. What you think about master-slave solution? maybe it will help?

Answer (score 0):

If you want stop that take long time execution SQL , here is how to stop it :

- connect to that MySQL server
- execute SQL `show processlist`
- find `id` with long execution time
- execute `kill [id]`